# FCM android - mismatch sender id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that uses FCM for sending push notification for multiple devices.

When I send notification I'm getting error:

> {"multicast_id":7972874062893873258,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

I've tried with both sever key and legacy server key, but getting the same error.

Used googleservice.json and uninstall the app after integrating the json.

I have researched a lot and made sure I have added all prerequisites that FCM needs.

Any suggestions?

```
function sendPushNotificationToFCMSever($token,$title, $desc, $API_SERVER_KEY) {  
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
        'registration_ids' => $token,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $title,
                "title" => "Title",
                "icon" => "myicon"
        )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
    $headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . $API_SERVER_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What do you pass in `registration_ids`?

Comment: array of device id's to send push notification

Comment: Can you try sending a message to the same token(s) via the console and see if it's showing an error as well?

Comment: @AL . Thanks for your comment. My tokens where wrong
I've created correct tocken for fcm and it works fine